# How can we build a node api which will send mail to users and will also generate otp for accessing my python microservices

Tags: python, email, one-time-password

Is there a way to write an email API on nodejs so that an email containing unique auto-generated OTP will be sent to the user in order to access my python micro-services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) is a popular module for sending email inside nodejs. You can find all the details on the website.

Alternatively, you can use 3rd party API for handling transactional emails. In my experience, [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) does the job and has a neat API that's easy to implement.

As far as OTP goes, you can use whatever you prefer to generate the password, just **never** use `Math.random` because it's not secure. In general, this is how I would structure my app:

1. Generate OTP using [generate-password](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-password), or however you see fit
2. Save the OTP hash to the database (you shouldn't store actual passwords to databases)
3. Send the email with your link using Nodemailer or a 3rd party transactional email provider
4. Once user does what he's instructed to do, you compare the OTP hash with the hash you have saved in your database, and react accordingly

If you need any code examples or anything else let me know and I'll edit my answer.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable solution #steven , i will ask you up further if i have any doubts